# Add Checkboxes to DataGridView and check/uncheck them

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, checkbox

I want to add a checkbox to every row in a `DataGridView`.
The `DataGridView` will be filled dynamically and when it is filled it should have a new column with name "Select" and that column should contain Checkboxes.

I used this code but its not working.

```
DataGridViewTextBoxColumn c = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
clsCol1.HeaderText = "Select";
clsCol1.ValueType = typeof(System.String);
this.dataGridView1.Columns.Add(clsCol1);
```

I have tried this code also

```
dataGridView1.Columns.Clear(); DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn c = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
{
    column.HeaderText = "Selected";
    column.Name = "Selected";
    column.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.DisplayedCells;
    column.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Standard;
    column.ThreeState = false;
    column.CellTemplate = new DataGridViewCheckBoxCell();
    column.CellTemplate.Style.BackColor = Color.Beige;
}
dataGridView1.Columns.Insert(0, column)
```

After the `DataGridView` is populated I want to make two buttons to check all and uncheck all checkboxes.

I am pretty inexperienced with C#, so any answers would be most appreciated.

Comment: Do note that the `DataGridView` is a *different* control than the `DataGrid`. The former is intended to replace the latter, but both are still available. It's important to be clear which one you're using.

Comment: Did you get your answer? if you did, mark it as the answer, if you found the answer yourself, can you edit your post explaining what you did. If you're still looking how to resolve your issue, you can give more details. (You can do this for all your questions)

Answer (score 1):

On the `CheckChanged event` of the CheckBox, you need to select/deselect all

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["CheckBoxColumnName"].Value = chkSelectAll.Checked;
}
```

After that, you might want to think about unchecking the SelectAll CheckBox when one row of the DataGridView is unchecked